# plot.ppp plotting characters and not displaying coordinates

Tags: r, spatstat

I have two sf objects that I wanted to plot side by side as ppp. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450593/merging-levels-such-that-n-in-window-is-equal-to-the-number-of-levels) question, the plot first worked fine and the plot was good, but then I clicked "Clear all plots" to produce two plots side by side. And after that the coordinates no longer show on either axis and one plot is showing characters as shown below. I even restarted R, but the results are still the same. Here is the code below, and the sample data can be downloaded from [here](https://app.box.com/s/hfzk41jd8msb9cjaj3fbww8h19c1b8gq). I don't know what went wrong after clearing the plotting window. How can this problem be fixed?

```
sf = st_read("~", "sf")
# Regrouping data
sf = sf::st_as_sf(sf, coords = c("Long", "Lat")) %>% 
  group_by(COOPID, STATION_NA) %>% 
  summarize(do_union=FALSE) 
# Counties 
sf_2 = st_read("~", "sf_2")
sf_2 = sf::st_as_sf(sf_2, coords = c("Long", "Lat")) %>% 
  group_by(COOPID, Manner_of_) %>% 
  summarize(do_union=FALSE) 
sf_flat = st_transform(sf, crs = 6345)
sf_2_flat = st_transform(sf_2, crs = 6345)
sf_ppp = maptools::as.ppp.SpatialPointsDataFrame(as_Spatial(sf_flat))
sf_2_ppp = maptools::as.ppp.SpatialPointsDataFrame(as_Spatial(sf_2_flat))
marks(sf_ppp) = factor(marks(Idaho_Stations__owin_c)$STATION_NA)
marks(sf_2_ppp) = factor(marks(Idaho_Stations__owin_c)$Manner_of_)
#Plot
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(sf_ppp, main = "sf ppp")
plot(sf_2_ppp, main = "sf_2 ppp")
```

[image]

I can also get this warning for sf_ppp:

```
Warning message:
In default.charmap(ntypes, chars) :
  Too many types to display every type as a different character
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of the point pattern datasets `sf_ppp` and `sf_2_ppp` has a vector of marks which is a `factor` classifying the points into different groups or types. In the jargon this is called a multitype point pattern.

The warning message says that one of these point patterns had too many types (that is, too many different possible levels of the factor) for them to be displayed using different plot characters selected from the plot characters available (in the base plotting system in R).

Taking a look at the plot you produced, the right-hand plot looks normal. It shows a multitype point pattern with 6 different types, which are listed at the side, along with the plot characters used to represent them. A triangle indicates a front-to-front collision, for example.

The left-hand plot is what happens when there are too many types. The code gives up trying to map the types (levels) to plot characters `pch`, and uses the alphabet (lower and upper case) instead, recycling the alphabet if there are more than 52 levels. It also truncates the list of possible types so that it can fit at the side of the plot. The code can't guess what you want to do in this case, but you can take charge, either by specifying the argument `chars` which maps the levels to plotting characters, or by merging some of the factor levels with `mergeLevels`.

Please consider spending some time to read Chapters 3 and 4 of the [spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org) which explain how to handle these data. Chapter 3 is available free.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. And an update that just now I started R studio with the same code without changing anything, and the results are back to normal https://app.box.com/s/k41izwmfdtvz86qawzi651g6gd6apj7t.So I don't know if this a glitch in the base plot function.  And this is actually what I wanted my plot to look like.

Comment: The second plot is also looking much nicer now (https://app.box.com/s/rpgo0e4gym74lkyt7yz1r4uexx6xkdaz), as it shows the x and y coordinates and the locations are properly displayed in the window. So I am guessing that "clicking clear plots" causes a glitch. The final plots side by side https://app.box.com/s/wdm0vvvos9qrvijy1qr8oh0kfunvkpvp